# SQL Join where two parameters must be in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using MS SQL Server 2014, and I got one table looking like this: (table1)

```
PropertyId
1 
2
3
4
```

And another table looking like this: (table2)

```
PropertyId   Filter
1            1
1            2
2            1
3            1
4            2
```

I want to get all properties from the first table having filter 1 AND 2 (in this case only PropertyId 1)

I can do this using:

```
Select * from table1 where id in (select PropertyId from table2 where filter = 1) AND (select PropertyId from table2 where filter = 2)
```

If I use join, I will get all properties that's in table2:

```
Select * from table1 join table2 on table1.PropertyId = table2.PropertyId where table2.Filter in (1,2)
```

Table1 got about 200'000 rows and table2 about 2'500'000 rows, so the solution must be really effective :)

**EDIT:**
Sorry for being so unclear in my question:

- Table1 contains 22 columns, and table2 contains 7 columns
- The query can have up to 13 filters, so the query must handle that
- If it's possible, I'd rather not have more then one or two selects

Comment: what is the output from this sample input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses aggregation.  If you don't need to filter by the first table, you can simply do:

```
select propertyId
from table2
where filter in (1, 2)
group by propertyId
having count(*) = 2;  -- "2" = number of things you are looking for
```

Note:  This assumes the property/filter values are unique in the second table.  Otherwise, you can use `count(distinct)`.

EDIT:

If you need to filter by the first table, just add it in:

```
select t2.propertyId
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.propertyId = t1.propertyId
where filter in (1, 2)
group by t2.propertyId
having count(*) = 2;  -- "2" = number of things you are looking for
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your answer, unfortunately, I have to filter by the first table

Comment: @MarcusOhlsson . . . That is easily handled.

Answer (score 0):

Use **inner Join** to only get the Connected Keys

```
Select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.PropertyId = table2.PropertyId where table2.Filter in (1,2)
```

Comment: Hi Sayed, unfortunately, using a inner join gets all rows from table2 having filter 1 OR 2, not 1 AND 2

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

```
select PropertyId
from table1
where PropertyId in
(
select t21.PropertyId
from table2 t21
inner join table2 t22 on t22.PropertyId = t21.PropertyId and t22.Filter = 2
where t21.Filter = 1
)
```

Comment: Hi @Neeray, your are right that this works when you have only 2 filters, but what happens if you have 12 filters :), sorry for not clarifying that in my fist question

Comment: @MarcusOhlsson When the question changes then the answer changes. Gordon Linoff's answer may be best suited in a situation when you have 12 filters as you can expand the IN list and change the count(*) to 12.